# Ballerina database read does not throw compiler error

Tags: ballerina

While following [1] it does not throw a compiler error if the select statement is as below.In this case 'id' could be either path/query param. Is this the expected behaviour?

```
 var response = customerDB->select("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id =? ",(),id);
```

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/taint-checking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you have given would not cause an SQL injection threat because you are not appending the id parameter to the query. You are passing the "id" value as a parameter to the select operation so that internally a proper prepared statement will be constructed. Therefore a compilation error would not occur.

Following should cause a compiler error.

```
    var response = customerDB->select("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id = " + id, ());
```

You can refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) for an example for SQL Injection.